# How to maintain state between page redirection JSf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I am making pages where you can upload pictures and then preview them. Both upload and preview work fine. But the problem is if I upload images, then preview it and then come back to the upload images page, the images are gone. Here is my code

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="4"
              border=""
              width="20%"
              style="position: absolute; top: 50px;"
              columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

              <h:outputText value="*" />
              <h:outputText value="Map: " />
              <p:fileUpload id="cityMap"
                            description="Image"
                            update="mapImage messages"
                            allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                            auto="true"
                            fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

              </p:fileUpload>

              <p:graphicImage id="mapImage"
                              value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                              width="80"
                              height="50"
                              cache="false" />

              <h:outputText value="*" />
              <h:outputText value="Image1: " />
              <p:fileUpload id="cityImage1"
                            description="Image"
                            update="city_Image1 messages"
                            allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                            auto="true"
                           fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

              </p:fileUpload>

              <p:graphicImage id="city_Image1"
                              value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                              width="80"
                              height="50"
                              cache="false" />



              <h:outputText value="*" />
              <h:outputText value="Image2: " />
              <p:fileUpload id="cityImage2"
                            description="Image"
                            update="city_Image2 messages"
                            allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                            auto="true"
                            fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

              </p:fileUpload>

              <p:graphicImage id="city_Image2"
                              value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                              width="80"
                              height="50"
                              cache="false" />
```

Here is my bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
public class CityDetail {

    private StreamedContent image;
    private ArrayList images;
    private ArrayList imageNames;
    private String imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";
    private String imagePath1 = "/resources/images" + "/";

    public CityDetail() {

        images = new ArrayList();
        images.add(null);
        images.add(null);
        images.add(null);
        images.add(null);
        images.add(null);

        imageNames = new ArrayList();
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");

    // Getting session ID from seession variable that is set in the City_Review Page
    cityID = Integer.parseInt(ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("CityID").toString());

        System.out.println();

    }

    public void imageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

        imagePath = "";

        // Variable to ensure that the query is always enter to same index.
        int index = -1;
        String query =  "";

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        // File
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

        // File Name
        String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();

        //File Extension
        String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length());

        String path = externalContext.getRealPath("/resources/images") + "/" ;


        try {

            //<p:fileUpload id="cityMap" .../>
            String componentID = event.getComponent().getClientId();

            if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityMap")) {

                index = 0;

                /**
                 * UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2,... WHERE    some_column=some_value
             */
                query = "UPDATE city set citymap=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

                boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "cityMap_" + cityID);
                boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("cityMap_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

                if (outcome) {

                    addImageNameToList(index, "cityMap_" + cityID + fileExtension);

                    setImage(imagePath1, "cityMap_" + cityID + fileExtension);
                    //imagePath = imagePath + "cityMap" + fileExtension;

                }

            } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage1")) {

                index = 1;
                query = "UPDATE city set cityimage1=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

                boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "cityImage1_" + cityID);
                boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("cityImage1_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

                if (outcome) {

                    addImageNameToList(index, "cityImage1_" + cityID + fileExtension);
                    setImage(imagePath1, "cityImage1_" + cityID + fileExtension);

                }

            } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage2")) {

                index = 2;
                query = "UPDATE city set cityimage2=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

                boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "cityImage2_" + cityID);
                boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("cityImage2_", fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

                if (outcome) {

                    addImageNameToList(index, "cityImage2_" + cityID + fileExtension);
                    setImage(imagePath1, "cityImage2_" + cityID + fileExtension);

                }

            } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage3")) {

                index = 3;
                query = "UPDATE city set cityimage3=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

                boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "cityImage3_" + cityID);
                boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("cityImage3_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

                if (outcome) {

                    addImageNameToList(index, "cityImage3_" + cityID + fileExtension);
                    setImage(imagePath1, "cityImage3_" + cityID + fileExtension);

                }

    } catch (Exception e) {

         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Exception happen");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

         e.printStackTrace();

        // return null;

     }

} //end of imageUpload()

private void setImage(String path, String fileName) {

     imagePath = path + fileName;

 }
```

Now when I come back to this page after previewing then the images gone. How can I prevent this? Do I make 5 image path variables and then save it somewhere else? But what if I have 50 images. Is there any better option?   That when I again come back to upload the page everything remains as it is to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are weird with your code:

- You have to select a **single** scope for your bean, ViewScoped **or** SesssionScoped.
- Should all h:graphicImage components be bound to the same value really?
- I can't see the imagePath property of your bean.

Comment: Hi i have done it. Yes i used same path for all images and i have done it using System events. I don't know how can i place code here in my comment . Also the limit is very limited else i show you my code. Every thing is working fine. Actually i used View Scope because i want that my constructor is not called when i press file upload button. Because i have 5 file upload buttons on my page and i noticed that each time i click on file upload button the constructor call. I used session scope because i save images name in a list and then save the list in the session variable.

Comment: If i use only view scope then how can i save images name to session. And if i only used view scope then my constructor call multiple times. That's why i used both scopes. IF this is bad practice please let me know because i want to know the best practices. Oh sorry actually i didn't show the getter property because it just return image path. Here is my property :)                                                   public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }                                                           Thanks :)

Comment: A managed bean can't have two scopes, and sessionscope lasts longer than viewscope so that's probably what you're after. If you want to keep a state of the page while navigating around, you have to put it in sessionscope, or perhaps use viewscope together with FlashScope (http://www.jroller.com/HazemBlog/entry/understanding_the_jsf_2_0). Flash scope can be used together with other scopes since it works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Either you store the images in a `@SessionScoped` bean, or you store them to some persistent storage after you upload them.

Comment: I am getting images from path ,not  from some image variable. If you see the code then for all <p:graphics /> i used the same path , then on the basis of ID i make pat and get image from that path. Also i used @SessionScoped annotation. Does this annotaion not represent that my bean has Session scoped? and the state is saved ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi here how i done this.  First here is my html

```
<h:form id="cityDetailForm" prependId="false" >

                <p:growl id="messages"
                         showDetail="true" />

                <p:panel id="panel1"
                         style="border-color: #000000;width: 954px;position: absolute;left: 150px;height: 450px;-moz-border-radius: 11px; -webkit-border-radius: 11px; border-radius: 11px; behavior: url(../PIE/PIE.htc)">

                    <strong Class="MainHeader">
                        <p:spacer width="10"/> City Detail
                    </strong>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="5"
                                 border=""
                                 width="20%"
                                 style="position: absolute; top: 50px;"
                                 columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Map: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityMap"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="city messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="city"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false">

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <p:commandLink update="city"
                                       action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline">

                            <h:outputText value="remove" />

                        </p:commandLink>


                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Image1: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityImage1"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="Image1 messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >


                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="Image1"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false" >

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <p:commandLink update="Image1"
                                       action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline">

                            <h:outputText value="remove" />

                        </p:commandLink>

                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Image2: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityImage2"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="Image2 messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="Image2"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false" >

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />


                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <p:commandLink update="Image2"
                                       action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline">

                            <h:outputText value="remove" />

                        </p:commandLink>



                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Image3: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityImage3"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="Image3 messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="Image3"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false" >

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />


                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <p:commandLink update="Image3"
                                       action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline">

                            <h:outputText value="remove" />

                        </p:commandLink>

                        <h:outputText value="*" />
                        <h:outputText value="Image4: " />
                        <p:fileUpload id="cityImage4"
                                      description="Image"
                                      update="Image4 messages"
                                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                                      auto="true"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

                        </p:fileUpload>

                        <p:graphicImage id="Image4"
                                        value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                                        width="80"
                                        height="50"
                                        cache="false" >

                            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

                        </p:graphicImage>

                        <p:commandLink update="Image4"
                                       action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                                       style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline">

                            <h:outputText value="remove" />

                        </p:commandLink>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:commandButton id="preview"
                                     value="Preview"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.preview}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 350px;"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle" />

                    <h:commandButton id="save"
                                     value="Save"
                                     actionListener="#{cityDetail.sendImagesToDatabase}"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.save}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 350px; left: 90px;"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle" />

                    <h:commandButton id="cancel"
                                     value="Cancel"
                                     action="#{cityDetail.cancel}"
                                     style="position: absolute; top: 350px; left: 165px;"
                                     styleClass="ButtonStyle" />

                </p:panel>

            </h:form>
```

and now here is my bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
public class CityDetail {

private StreamedContent image;
private ArrayList images;
private ArrayList imageNames;
private String imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";
private String imagePath1 = "/resources/images" + "/";
private boolean remove = false;
private String once;

private static int x = 0;

// Set in the City_Review Page, in session variable
public int cityID;

/** Creates a new instance of CityDetail */
public CityDetail() {



    /**
     * If we come from cityView.xhtml page then this contain value. We are using this because we
     * want that when user come from cityView.xhtml  page then old values should be retain.
     */
    imageNames = (ArrayList)ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("cityDetailImageNames");
    images = (ArrayList)ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("cityDetailImages");


    if (imageNames == null) {

        imageNames = new ArrayList();
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");
        imageNames.add("");

    } //end of if()

    if (images == null) {

        images = new ArrayList();
        images.add("");
        images.add("");
        images.add("");
        images.add("");
        images.add("");

    }

    // Getting session ID from seession variable that is set in the City_Review Page
    cityID = Integer.parseInt(ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("CityID").toString());

    once = ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("once").toString();

    if (once.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

        //SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name operator value 
        String cityMapQuery = "SELECT citymap From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";
        String cityImage1Query = "SELECT cityimage1 From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";
        String cityImage2Query = "SELECT cityimage2 From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";
        String cityImage3Query = "SELECT cityimage3 From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";
        String cityImage4Query = "SELECT cityimage4 From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";

        ArrayList cityMapQueryArray = new ArrayList();
        cityMapQueryArray.add(cityMapQuery); 

        ArrayList cityImage1QueryArray = new ArrayList();
        cityImage1QueryArray.add(cityImage1Query);

        ArrayList cityImage2QueryArray = new ArrayList();
        cityImage2QueryArray.add(cityImage2Query);

        ArrayList cityImage3QueryArray = new ArrayList();
        cityImage3QueryArray.add(cityImage3Query);

        ArrayList cityImage4QueryArray = new ArrayList();
        cityImage4QueryArray.add(cityImage4Query);

        ArrayList mainArray = new ArrayList();

        mainArray.add(cityMapQueryArray);
        mainArray.add(cityImage1QueryArray);
        mainArray.add(cityImage2QueryArray);
        mainArray.add(cityImage3QueryArray);
        mainArray.add(cityImage4QueryArray);


    } //end of if



    System.out.println();

} //end of constructor()

//Getters and setters ---------------------

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(StreamedContent image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

//public String imageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
public void imageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    imagePath = "";

    // Variable to ensure that the query is always enter to same index.
    int index = -1;
    String query =  "";

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    // File
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

    // File Name
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();

    //File Extension
    String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length());

    String path = externalContext.getRealPath("/resources/images") + "/" ;

    try {

        //<p:fileUpload id="cityMap" .../>
        String componentID = event.getComponent().getClientId();

        if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityMap")) {

            index = 0;

            /**
             * UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2,... WHERE some_column=some_value
             */
            query = "UPDATE city set citymap=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

            boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "cityMap_" + cityID);
            boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("cityMap_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

            if (outcome) {

                addImageNameToList(index, "cityMap_" + cityID + fileExtension);
               // setImage(imagePath1, "cityMap_" + cityID + fileExtension, index);
               // imagePath = imagePath1 + "cityMap_" + cityID + fileExtension;

            }

        } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage1")) {

            index = 1;
            query = "UPDATE city set cityimage1=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

            boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "sityImage1_" + cityID);
            boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("sityImage1_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

            if (outcome) {

                addImageNameToList(index, "sityImage1_" + cityID + fileExtension);

            }

        } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage2")) {

            index = 2;
            query = "UPDATE city set cityimage2=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

            boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "sityImage2_" + cityID);
            boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("sityImage2_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

            if (outcome) {

                addImageNameToList(index, "sityImage2_" + cityID + fileExtension);

            }

        } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage3")) {

            index = 3;
            query = "UPDATE city set cityimage3=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

            boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "sityImage3_" + cityID);
            boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("sityImage3_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

            if (outcome) {

                addImageNameToList(index, "sityImage3_" + cityID + fileExtension);

            }

        } else if (componentID.equalsIgnoreCase("cityImage4")) {

            index = 4;
            query = "UPDATE city set cityimage4=(?) where cityid=" + cityID;

            boolean reslut =  ConnectionUtil.deleteImageIfExist(path, "sityImage4_" + cityID);
            boolean outcome = ConnectionUtil.createFile("sityImage4_" + cityID, fileExtension ,path, uploadedFile);

            if (outcome) {

                addImageNameToList(index, "sityImage4_" + cityID + fileExtension);

            }

        } //end of  else if()

        // Convert file from input stream to bytes
         byte[] byteArray = event.getFile().getContents();

        /**
         * Add images to list so we can retrieve them when user click on save button
         */
       // boolean add = images.add(new Images(query, byteArray));


         //Check for multiple clicks on the same Browse Button
         // If index has value then replace the value rather then add new value to List
         images.set(index, new Images(query, byteArray));



        //byteArray used to store picture into database
        InputStream ist = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

        /*
         * StreamedContent Object used to show the picture in jsf pages. We need to convert
         * again bytearray to InputStream
         */
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(ist, "image/jpg");


        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(fileName + " succesfully uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        //we dont need to use faces-config to navigate in jsf 2
       // return null ;

     } catch (Exception e) {

         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Exception happen");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

         e.printStackTrace();

        // return null;

     } //end of catch (Exception e)

} //end of imageUpload()

/**
  * This method called when user click on "save" button on page cityDetail.xhtml .
  * This method is called before save() function is executed. Because action listener
  * runs first.
  * @return
  */
 public void sendImagesToDatabase(ActionEvent e) {

     ArrayList mainArray = new ArrayList();

     for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++) {

         ArrayList innerArray = new ArrayList();

         if (images.get(i).equals("")) {

             continue;

         } else {

             Images imageObject =(Images)images.get(i);

             String query = imageObject.getQuery();
             byte[] image = imageObject.getImageBytes();

             innerArray.add(query);
             innerArray.add(image);

             mainArray.add(innerArray);

         }

     } //end of for()

     int executeDocumentUpdateBatch = ConnectionUtil.executeDocumentUpdateBatch(mainArray);

     System.out.println(executeDocumentUpdateBatch);

 } //end of sendImagesToDatabase()

 /**
  * This method is called when user click on "preview" button on page cityDetail.xhtml
  * @return
  */
 public String preview() {

     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImageNames", imageNames);
     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImages", images);

     return "cityView?faces-redirect=true";

 } //end of preview()

 /**
  * This method called when user click on "save" button on page cityDetail.xhtml .
  * This method is called after sendImagesToDatabase() function is executed. Because action listener
  * runs first.
  * @return
  */
 public String save() {

     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImageNames", imageNames);
     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImages", images);

     return "cityDetail?faces-redirect=true";
     //return null;

 } //end of save()

 public String cancel() {

     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImageNames", null);
     ConnectionUtil.session.setAttribute("cityDetailImages", null);

     return "City_AddUpdate?faces-redirect=true";

 } //end of cancel()

 private void addImageNameToList(int index, String fileName) {

       imageNames.set(index, fileName);

 } //end of addImageNameToList()

 /**
  * This method is called when user click on remove link on page cityDetail.xhtml  beside each image.
  * We simply set boolean variable "remove" to true so when "update = <p:graphicImage Id />"
  * in <p:commandLink /> is called then <p:graphicImage /> with the mentioned ID is called and
  * its putImage() method is called. Then in the method we handle remove image procedure.
  */
 public void removeImage() {

     remove = true;

 } //end of removeImage()

 /**
  * This method is called for every  <p:graphicImage /> because we use "type = preRenderComponent"
  * on every <p:graphicImage /> . In this method we we set image path and also check whether
  * user coming from preview page so we can again set images to the same position.
  * @param event
  */
 public void putImage(ComponentSystemEvent event) {

     boolean test = remove;

     boolean found = false;



     x++;
     int y = x;

     GraphicImage image1 = (GraphicImage)event.getComponent();

     String imageURL = image1.getUrl();
     String imageDir = image1.getDir();
     String imageValue = image1.getValue().toString();
     String imageId = image1.getClientId();

     ArrayList imagesNames = (ArrayList)ConnectionUtil.session.getAttribute("cityDetailImageNames");

     if (imagesNames == null) {

         for (int i=0; i<imageNames.size(); i++) {

             String fileName = imageNames.get(i).toString();

             if (fileName.contains(imageId)) {

                 if (remove) {

                     imagePath = "";
                     imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";

                     //also remove from list so when on  preview page this list called using session
                     // it contains "" for the remove value. Otherwise image deleted from
                     //cityDetail page but shown when preview is clicked
                     imageNames.set(i, "");
                     remove = false;
                     break;

                 } else {

                     imagePath = "";
                     imagePath = imagePath1 + fileName;
                     break;

                 }

             } //end of if

         } //end of for()

     } else {  //handle when retrun from preview page

         for(int i=0; i<imagesNames.size(); i++) {

             String fileName = imagesNames.get(i).toString();

             if (fileName.contains(imageId)) {

                 if (remove) {

                     imagePath = "";
                     imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";
                     imageNames.set(i, ""); //also remove from list
                     remove = false;
                     break;

                 } else {

                     imagePath = "";
                     imagePath = imagePath1 + fileName;
                     break;

                 }

             } else if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                 imagePath = "";
                 imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";
                 break;

             }

         } //end of for

     }

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println();



 } //end of putImage



} //end of class CityDetail
```

Now if i done anything wrong and unusal then please let me know ? because this code is working fine but working fine doesn't mean that it is perfect or correct.

Thanks